# Where does WebClient stores data he downloads?

Tags: c#, webclient, data-storage

I am writing an app that downloads a ton of json data (like 20 gb a day, thousands of 2-3 mb per attempt), but stores only like 0.001% of it.

I want to know where does it stores temporary data, does it saves it on hdd or stores in RAM?

Can I change the location where it puts the data, if it stores it on HDD?

Comment: DownloadString stores data in RAM, is not using any temp files on HDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stores everything in RAM.

You can decompile it or refer to [reference sources](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs).

I think `DownloadBits` method is good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebClient.DownloadFile then the second argument of this method let's you specify where to store the file. 
If you use WebClient.DownloadData you will get data in bytes that you will need to persist. 
WebClient.DownloadString is similar where you will get JSON as string that you can persist.

Comment: I am using WebClient.DownloadString and downloading like 3 megabytes per attempt. Where does it go, ram or some temporary file on hdd?

Comment: Without knowing the API it is a bit difficult to tell streaming vs blocking. By default downloadstring should return all of the call response. DownloadStringAsync or the task based alternative may be more helpful if you want to receive data in chunks.